# Voltage and current through 2 resistors on circuit

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage

Given the circuit below, with a dc supply of 25V and the resistors as are, I am asked to find the Voltage on the ends of $3.3 \Omega$ resistor and the current through the $25 \Omega$ resistor. I need some help as I don't know how to proceed.

[image: circuit]

I tried using the KCL and KVL and ended up saying that; If I set the clock wise as the positive movement of the current, (setting Voltage Source = $\epsilon$, $10\Omega = R_4, 3.3 \Omega = R_3, 25\Omega = R_5$)then we have that:
$$ \epsilon -R_3 I_1 - R_4I = 0, \epsilon - R_5I_2 - R_4I = 0, I = I_1 + I_2$$

but I don't know how to continue. any help? Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Equivalent resistance in the circuit is

$$R_e=10+\frac{3.3×25}{3.3+25}=12.9 \Omega$$

Since for parallel combinations, reciprocal of equivalent resistance is equal to sum of reciprocal of parallel resistances, and for series, the equivalent resistance is merely the sum of the resistances in series.

Using ohms law,

Current in circuit
$$I=\frac VR$$$$=\frac {25}{12.9}=1.9 A$$

So voltage dropped across the $10\Omega$ resistor is, again using Ohms law $IR=1.9×10 V=19V$.

So voltage dropped across the parallel combination of equivalent resistance of $2.9\Omega=25-19=6V$.

So now

Current through $25 \Omega$ resistor $$= \frac VR=\frac {6}{25}=0.24A$$

And the voltage dropped across $3.3 \Omega$ resistance is $6V$ itself, as voltage dropped across each resistor is same for resistors connected in parallel, their end points being the same.